# Java/Selenium webdriver: Unable to click the captcha icon

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a portal where I need to match the text displayed with the captcha icon displayed. Every captcha icon has a src tag URL. I have extracted the text from URL using pattern. But, unable to print the text if it matches text in if/else if blocks.

How to print the text if the string matches expected text?

HTML:

```
<div id="captchaID_AN" captcha="" class="row custompanel captcha"><div class="small-12 columns margin-btm--small"><label class="captchalabel">Select the ( Computer ) </label><input id="captchaID_AN_hidden" name="captchaID_AN_hidden" type="hidden"><label for="captchaID_AN" data-error=""></label></div><div class="small-12 columns"><div class="small-2 columns captchaheight"><a class="captcha-items__item"><img id="5eb1f65fc77427a180aebfafa00f8d36" src="/obweb/javax.faces.resource/img/assets/computer.png.jsf?ln="></a></div><div class="small-2 columns captchaheight"><a class="captcha-items__item"><img id="d3d876396aea3e8da304747e4e4ffc9f" src="/obweb/javax.faces.resource/img/assets/music-note.png.jsf?ln="></a></div><div class="small-2 columns captchaheight"><a class="captcha-items__item"><img id="93bb735cad5164b841132845a33c9054" src="/obweb/javax.faces.resource/img/assets/balloons.png.jsf?ln="></a></div><div class="small-2 columns captchaheight"><a class="captcha-items__item"><img id="db9b4dc10f5eb9dbe350b68b3cd02126" src="/obweb/javax.faces.resource/img/assets/house.png.jsf?ln="></a></div><div class="small-2 columns captchaheight"><a class="captcha-items__item"><img id="dd9ba4c935057e29b55c99f3316ce004" src="/obweb/javax.faces.resource/img/assets/scissors.png.jsf?ln="></a></div><div class="small-2 columns"><a id="captchaID_AN_link" href="#" class=" icon-refresh captcharefresh " ng-click="click($event,{s:&quot;captchaID_AN&quot;,p:&quot;registrationenterdetails&quot;,u:&quot;captchaID_AN&quot;,iau:true,imm:true});" tabindex="0"><span class="icon refresh " style="margin-right:5px"></span>Reload</a></div></div></div>
```

code :

```
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Select the ')]"));
String texts = text.getText();

System.out.println("Text is:" + texts);

replacetext = texts.substring(texts.indexOf("(") + 1, texts.indexOf(")"));
System.out.println("replacedtextis:" + replacetext);

List < WebElement > list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-12 columns']/div/a/img"));

String firstcaptcha = list.get(0).getAttribute("src");
String secondcaptcha = list.get(1).getAttribute("src");
String thirdcaptcha = list.get(2).getAttribute("src");
String fourthcaptcha = list.get(3).getAttribute("src");
String fifthcaptcha = list.get(4).getAttribute("src");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("assets/(\\w+.\\w+)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(firstcaptcha);
Matcher m1 = p.matcher(secondcaptcha);
Matcher m2 = p.matcher(thirdcaptcha);
Matcher m3 = p.matcher(fourthcaptcha);
Matcher m4 = p.matcher(fifthcaptcha);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));

    int test = m.group(1).indexOf(".");

    if (test != -1) {
        subString = m.group(1).substring(0, test); //
        System.out.println("value is:" + subString);
    }


}

if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(1));

    int test1 = m1.group(1).indexOf(".");

    if (test1 != -1) {
        substring1 = m1.group(1).substring(0, test1); //
        System.out.println("value is:" + substring1);
    }

}
if (m2.find()) {
    System.out.println(m2.group(1));

    int test2 = m2.group(1).indexOf(".");

    if (test2 != -1) {
        substring2 = m2.group(1).substring(0, test2); //
        System.out.println("value is:" + substring2);

    }
}
if (m3.find()) {
    System.out.println(m3.group(1));

    int test3 = m3.group(1).indexOf(".");

    if (test3 != -1) {
        substring3 = m3.group(1).substring(0, test3); //
        System.out.println("value is:" + substring3);
    }
}
if (m4.find()) {
    System.out.println(m4.group(1));

    int test4 = m4.group(1).indexOf(".");

    if (test4 != -1) {
        substring4 = m4.group(1).substring(0, test4); //
        System.out.println("value is:" + substring4);
    }
}

System.out.println("returned valueis:" + subString);
System.out.println("returned valueis:" + substring1);
System.out.println("returnedvalueis:" + substring2);
System.out.println("returnedvalueis:" + substring3);
System.out.println("returnedvalueis:" + substring4);

if (subString.matches(replacetext)) {
    System.out.println("first captcha matched");

} else if (substring1.matches(replacetext)) {
    System.out.println("second captcha matched");

} else if (substring2.matches(replacetext)) {
    System.out.println("third captcha matched");

} else if (substring3.matches(replacetext)) {
    System.out.println("fourth captcha matched");

} else if (substring4.matches(replacetext)) {
    System.out.println("fifth captcha matched");
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: There are a few things that you might want to try: For example your substring `replacetext` has a space at start. What you can do is use `trim` function of `String`. Also while matching what you can do is keep both the strings in the same case. Or make your `Pattern` case insensitive.

Comment: @hiren thanks it worked. I have used trim() function and replaced matches with equalsIgnoreCase and I am able to select desired captcha. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**CAPTCHA** stands for:

**Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart**

So, by definition, resolving a **CAPTCHA** cannot be automated: Otherwise it could not tell computers and humans apart and hence fails being a **CAPTCHA.**

In order to solve it, there is something you can do - to use API of external services such as http://www.deathbycaptcha.com. You implementing their API, passing them the CAPTCHA and get in return the text.